# Why I find two elements using xpath when I specify index?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing autotests.
For finding elements I'm using XPATH.
Now I need get list of element, as usual I write xpath which contains class name of table and childs elements. My page has 2 tables, and my XPATH can find both, but when I'm using index 1 I also find second table, when I'm using index 2 I find nothing.

How does it work? Why I can't choose second element

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). Are you trying to find the second tbody in the first table, or are you trying to find the tbody of the second table?

Comment: I'm trying to find <tr> elements from first table and use xpath on screen like a parent for these elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the reason liesin the red part of your XPath.

So in the red part of your XPath will have 2 elements with a table.

To only select the first one you can put `()` around them like this:

```
(//div[@class='with-some-classname']/following-sibling::table)[1]/tbody
```

An other option would be to use the table as a predicate in your red part of the XPath like this i.e.:

```
(//div[@class='with-some-classname'][following-sibling::table])[1]/following-sibling::table[1]/tbody
```

Answer (score 0):

From the pieces of the XPath that I can see, at the step in which you are selecting the `tbody` element that is the child of the first following-sibling `table` element.

Most `table` will only have one `tbody` element.

So, in the first XPath where you add `[1]` asking for the first `tbody`, you get it. In the second XPath where you are asking for `[2]`, the second `tbody` that is the child of that `table`, there aren't any to select and you get nothing.

Comment: For the future. Did I understand correctly that chrome devtools can show me elements which I can't chose?